# Find Index where every value from list appeard in df

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I am trying to find the point wehere every number from my list appared in my df. I want to get the Index where the last number from my list is found in my df.

I tried it with a for loop:

```
   b=[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0, 23.0, 24.0, 25.0]
  
a=b

for a in df['windspeed']:
        print(df['Index'])
```

My df has around 250.000 rows
Here is a part of my df:

```
    Date    Hour    Minute  windspeed power
0   01.01.2018  0   0   10.2    2236
1   01.01.2018  0   0   10.7    2371
2   01.01.2018  0   0   9.5     2371
3   01.01.2018  0   0   10.5    2530
4   01.01.2018  0   10  9.1     1601
5   01.01.2018  0   10  9.3     1681
6   01.01.2018  0   10  8.6     1755
7   01.01.2018  0   10  9.1     1680
8   01.01.2018  0   20  9.8     1928
9   01.01.2018  0   20  10.0    2175
10  01.01.2018  0   20  8.9     1879
11  01.01.2018  0   20  9.3     1782
12  01.01.2018  0   30  9.8     2041
13  01.01.2018  0   30  9.6     2133
14  01.01.2018  0   30  8.8     2056
15  01.01.2018  0   30  10.4    2573
16  01.01.2018  0   40  9.4     2024
17  01.01.2018  0   40  10.3    2663
18  01.01.2018  0   40  9.0     2252
19  01.01.2018  0   40  10.4    2614
20  01.01.2018  0   50  9.2     1975
21  01.01.2018  0   50  10.4    2631
22  01.01.2018  0   50  9.2     2471
23  01.01.2018  0   50  10.1    2659
24  01.01.2018  1   0   10.6    2560
25  01.01.2018  1   0   10.6    2550
26  01.01.2018  1   0   9.8     2551
27  01.01.2018  1   0   10.8    2807
28  01.01.2018  1   10  11.0    2648
29  01.01.2018  1   10  11.1    2759
30  01.01.2018  1   10  10.6    2913
31  01.01.2018  1   10  11.5    3051
32  01.01.2018  1   20  12.1    1112
33  01.01.2018  1   20  11.8    1072
```

Comment: Can you add a sample dataframe to show what's going wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added a part of my df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With minimal modifications to your code I think you want this:

```
for number in b:
    if number in df['windspeed']:
        print(df['windspeed'].where(df['windspeed'] == number).last_valid_index())
```

This will just print the index of each value one at a time.

EDIT: To get the last index if found you can use the modified code above.

Comment: I want to get the Index where every number is found at leat one time in the df.

Comment: The first code does that. You can get them all in a list by doing this.`my_index = [df.index[df['windspeed'] == number ] if number in df['windspeed'] for number in b]`

Comment: Thanks for your help. The last thing in your comment dosen't work. And if I just do the previous method with the the print it works but shows me every Index in which one of the numbers in b appears. Is there a way to just show me the Index of the the last value of b?  I don't mean 25 I mean whatever wind speed comes up last.
Hopefully that's kind of understandable.

Comment: So are you saying that there is multiple windspeeds that are matched and you just want to get the last match ?

Comment: Ok I don't really know how to explain it, sorry. I will give you an example. The wind speed from 3-15 m/s are the most common in my df. Maybe in March there are high windspeed and it reaches the 25 m/s. But the 18 m/s is the last on my list missing from my df. Than the 18 m/s comes up in September. So I want to get the Index of the 18 m/s in Septmeber. If my list matches one of the windspeeds from my df it should be "deleted" and searched for the next one until every wind speed is found. And that Index where the last windspeed is found should be my print or output.

Comment: Ok did you try the modified code above I think that should do it for you.

Comment: It works but it shows me every position where the wind speed is found `Int64Index([1503, 1631, 1697, 1707, 13484, 13488, 13492, 16212, 16213, 43224,
            65601, 208677],
           dtype='int64')
Int64Index([1483, 1628, 1640, 1689, 1693, 1695, 10040], dtype='int64')`

Comment: Hmm I don't quite understand what you want, could you try and post an expected output on a small sample?

Comment: Something like this: `print(max(df.index[df['windspeed']) == number])` Output: `Index = 16667`

Comment: See latest edit above. This should give you the last occurring index of each value in your list.

Comment: I am sorry but I get an Sytanx Error: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: sorry - remove the square brackets

Comment: Perfect...Thank you so much!